# history push url not reinitialise the component again in case of dynamic route change

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a route defined as `/:business_id/:branch_id/user`. When I change the url from `/1/1/user` to `/1/2/user` using `history.push('/1/2/user')` the component is not re-rendered.

```
handleChange(val) {
   const { history, route: { match: { path, params: { business_id, tabKey, mode }}}} = this.context.router;
   let url = path.replace(':branch_id', val)
        .replace(':business_id', business_id)
        .replace(':tabKey', tabKey)
        .replace(':mode', mode);
    history.push(url);
}
```

Comment: where is router implementation ?

Comment: Please complete your question with the complete component code

Comment: react-router-dom used.

Comment: <BrowserRouter>
    <App>
      <Switch>
        <PrivateRoute path="/:business_id/:branch_id/team" component={TeamPage} />
      </Switch>
    </App>
  </BrowserRouter>